# How to Load variable into module exports, then use later

Tags: node.js

So I have two files

hi.js

```
var ext = require('./external.js')

ext.loadArray()
hello = ext.getRandom()
console.log(hello) // prints ['hey','hello','hi']
```

external.js

```
module.exports = {
      helloArray : [],
      loadArray: function(){
            //code that loads an array, ill manually enter for ? sake
            helloArray = ['hey','hello','hi'] 
      },
      getRandom: function(){
            return helloArray
      }
}
```

In the end i want to return a random index of helloArray, but it is not getting populated.  When I add console.log(helloArray) after calling loadarray the file is there, but it doesnt make it to the getRandom Function.  The loadArray loads info from an api, so i dont want to make a call to that api since it does not change.

How can the get Random function access the helloArray? For now disregard the API and we can work with ['hey','hello','hi']

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: `helloArray` is a property of `exports`, not something you can refer to randomly by a function that is another property of `exports`. As CertainPerformance says: this is impossible to reason about without beautifying because most people have better things to do than try to figure out a wall of code.

Comment: What's that random `close function` text doing there? It's not valid. Is it supposed to be a comment? What's the point of putting comments indicating something the syntax and indentation already indicates?

Comment: Sorry I am new here

Comment: In any case, if you don't need to expose the array to the outside world, don't put it in the exports, just make it a variable, and reference it in the functions you *do* intend to export. If you *also* need to expose the array, then include as one of the exports, but don't *declare* it in the exports.

Comment: I have multiple clients connecting to this server and they need to have this information. the reason i am setting it up like this now is that i dont have to update 5 clients, i can have the clients pull from this. Would this be the best way to set it up or do you suggest otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` referring to object properties from object methods:

```js
module.exports = {
      helloArray: [],
      loadArray: function(){
            //code that loads an array, ill manually enter for ? sake
            this.helloArray = ['hey','hello','hi']
      },
      getRandom: function(){
            return this.helloArray
      }
}
```

However, if you need not export `helloArray`, you can try this:

```js
var helloArray;

module.exports = {
      loadArray: function(){
            //code that loads an array, ill manually enter for ? sake
            helloArray = ['hey','hello','hi']
      },
      getRandom: function(){
            return helloArray
      }
}
```

Comment: this is not working.

When i call the .getRandom function, the array is [].

Comment: Do you run exactly this code or replace the function body with your real case? If you have asynchronous calls, the array will be empty with this approach, Exactly this code with synchronous calls only works properly as per my testing.

Comment: Hey sorry, i have one more question. I am a bit confused with async and sync and was wondering if i add a main() method to hi.js, add in ext.loadArray(), how can i want for this function to wait, before calling hello = ext.getRandom(), and console.log(hello)

Comment: Unfortunately, asynchronous code is contagious: you need to refactor all approach and use callbacks or Promises in both files. For example, You can make `ext.loadArray()` return a Promise after the array populating is complete. Then you can make your `main()` function `async` and then `await` the `ext.loadArray()` before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write code like this

hi.js

```
var ext = new require('./external.js')

ext.loadArray()
console.log(ext.getRandom()) // prints ['hey','hello','hi']
console.log(ext.helloArray) // prints ['hey','hello','hi']
```

external.js

```
function external() {
    this.helloArray = [];
}
external.prototype.loadArray = function(){
    //code that loads an array, ill manually enter for ? sake
     this.helloArray = ['hey','hello','hi'] 
};

external.prototype.getRandom = function(){
    return  this.helloArray
};
module.exports = external;
```